# Why is the picture not hidden under the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I do drag and drop on the image by assigning absolute positioning to the image. But when dragging an image, it goes beyond the viewing-area. I assigned it overflow: auto, that is, scrolling should appear, but the image just pops out. How to hide an image under the viewing-area when it goes beyond it?

https://jsfiddle.net/jakLc1wx/

```
<div class="viewing-area"></div>
<form name="insert_image">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="file-input" placeholder="">
    <input type="url" name="url" class="url-input" placeholder="https://example.com">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Добавить" class="submit">
    <input type="button" name="submit2" value="Добавить (файлом)" class="submit2">
</form>
```

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(72.21deg, #141812 -0.34%, #161422 28.25%, #1C0D0D 68.52%, #1A0623 96.34%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.viewing-area {
  width: 842px;
  height: 553px;
  background: white;

  border: 6px solid #4D4C4C;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: auto;

  img {
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
  }
}

input[type="file"] {
  color: white;
}
```

```
let insert_image = document.forms.insert_image;
let url_input = document.querySelector('.url-input');
let file_input = document.querySelector('.file-input');
let submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
let viewing_area = document.querySelector('.viewing-area');
let submit2 = document.querySelector('.submit2');

function dragImage (event) {
    let image = event.target;
    let shiftX = event.clientX - image.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - image.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let width = image.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    let height = image.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    image.style.position = 'absolute';
    image.style.maxWidth = width + 'px';
    image.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';


    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        image.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        image.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }

    viewing_area.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    image.onmouseup = function() {
        viewing_area.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        image.onmouseup = null;
    };

}


function insertByUrl(event) {
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = url_input.value;
    viewing_area.append(image);
    image.ondragstart = function () {
        return false;
    };
    image.addEventListener('mousedown', dragImage);
}

function insertByFile() {
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    let file = file_input.files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    fileReader.onload = function () {
        image.src = fileReader.result;
    }

    viewing_area.append(image);

    image.ondragstart = function () {
        return false;
    };
    image.addEventListener('mousedown', dragImage);
}


submit.addEventListener('click', insertByUrl);
submit2.addEventListener('click', insertByFile);
```

I tried to use z-index but it didn't work out. Perhaps it's the positioning of the parent, or its z-index

Comment: What happens if you add `body { overflow: hidden; }`? Also, your `img` CSS rule is inside the rule for the `.viewing-area`.

Comment: The problem is that scrolling must be present.

Comment: Ah, alright.. Then all you need is `position:relative` for your `.viewing-area`. Try that.